ROS2 for Material Handling Storage & Retrieval application
In my application we are going to perform Storage & retrieval operation using Robot who doesn't have LIDAR or ultrasonic sensors for navigation. We have QR code or RFID for to navigate on X axis positions and sensor based position on Z axis. So in this case my question will ROS2 support to run the application. In conventional way we use PLC's to control the motion and software provides source & destination.
